# Do I need Attic Fan in Garage?

Tags: roof, attic

My garage is about 20" x 24" and I have made attic in the Garage by adding plywood, insulation & sheet-rock, It is nicely done and as soon I finish this project, i realize, i do not any ventilation. I do have furnace in Attic.

Please provide feedback and suggestion, if i need to have Attic Fan?

BTW, I am live in San Francisco South Bay, CA.

Comment: The furnace exhaust is (hopefully!) piped outside; is the furnace air supply piped outside? And, where is the warm area created by the insulation: in the garage (with the insulation on the garage ceiling/attic floor)?

Comment: Why do you have a furnace in your garage attic?

Comment: attics aren't normally insulated and sheetrocked. Is this an attic (ie, empty storage) or is this actually habitable living space?

Comment: VTC - this is vague, the OP hasn't been back in 6 years, and I assume without bothering to check that the comment indicating that the sole answer is plagiarized is likely true.

Answer (score 0):

Roofs need to be ventilated to remove excess moisture and to inprove teh effectiveness of your insulation.  In the summer, improper ventilation can cause attic heat to build in excess of 160°F. This super-heated air eventually penetrates the ceiling insulation into the living area below.
  In the winter, warm interior air leaking through the insulation can cause condensation and can contribute to excess moisture build-up. Improperly ventilated attics will allow this moisture to collect and cling to the underside of the roof. The moisture will condense and fall, soaking the attic insulation and reducing its efficiency.
  You should install roof vents.  There should be a air passageway that allows air from the eaves to be drawn in and exit through roof vents. This all can be passive and does not require a fan.

Comment: Plagiarism ain't cool. https://www.gaf.com/Roofing/Residential/Products/Roof_Vents??r=1232394903&CBViewer=6886